# Eigenvalues and Harris Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, image-processing

In image processing is possible to detect a corner by looking at the eigenvalues of the Harris matrix.

Harris matrix can be here http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html
A corner is detected if there is a big variation in both the x and y direction, but how can this be translated to use eigenvector and eigenvalues. How just same outcome occur when the Eigenvalues is big?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might want to try stackoverflow.